# "Unexpected error. ok" in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have seen this error first time and I never had this before can anybody tell me what is this error about?

the only new thing what I have done is add this line of code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts.SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

error:

```
 Unexpected error. ok

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1002
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 809
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 709
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line 803
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line 329
```

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the Firefox driver supports the page load timeout? I'm not, and I said as much in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Hi Jim, you said `Firefox does too I think` so you were not sure :)